# how can I get the url of my youtube playlist into another website?

Tags: javascript

I found a you tube video tutorials online, with thumbnails. which I made some changes to suit my needs. Now the problem is I don't know how the url playlist was copied from you tube. Hope somebody can help me out here.

```
 var playListURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/B2A4E1367126848D?v=2&alt=json&callback=?';
    $.getJSON(playListURL, function (data) {
        var list_data = "";
        $.each(data.feed.entry, function (i, item) {
            var feedTitle = item.title.$t;
            var feedURL = item.link[1].href;
            var fragments = feedURL.split("/");
            var videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
            var thumb = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoID + "/default.jpg";
            list_data += '<a class="video_thumb" data-video-id="' + videoID + '" title="' + feedTitle + '"><img class="img img-polaroid" alt="' + feedTitle + '" src="' + thumb + '"</a>';
        });
        $(list_data).appendTo(".playlist");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a div with class `playlist` and using jQuery library.

```
<div class="playlist" >
    <p>Your PlayList</p>
</div>
```

Here the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reudxzs8/)